# Pharo 9.0 warning message on starting - "The current VM does not support TFFI Callbacks."

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

When I start a Pharo 9.0 x64 image with the Pharo 2.2 Launcher on Ubuntu 20.10, I get the following warning:

`The current VM does not support TFFI Callbacks. It will use the old implementation.`

I assume this is a reference to threaded FFI being added to the VM in the near future. Is there a way to use a newer VM that supports TFFI?

The only other post I could find on the internet relating to this warning is [this one](http://forum.world.st/Error-message-when-open-a-fresh-Pharo-9-fresh-image-td5126587.html).

Thank you so much for reading this!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, to get the newest VM you can go to "edit configurations" and then check to use the headless vm:

[image]

[image]